# there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "category"?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to define more than one foreign key in the process table. but I am getting the error that the columns I am trying to define as foreign key are not 'unique value'.

For this, I wanted to define id and name columns as primary keys in category and subject tables. However, when I want to create the process table, I still get this error." there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "category"

I have researched and continue to do so on Stackoverflow and many more. but I couldn't figure it out with solutions or viewpoints of the issues that got the same error I was facing. Maybe there is something I'm not seeing.

first table;

```
CREATE TABLE category(
    category_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    category_name VARCHAR(210),
    category_description TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT category_pk PRIMARY KEY(category_id,category_name)
    
);
```

second table;

```
CREATE TABLE subject(
    subject_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    subject_name VARCHAR(210),
    subject_description TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT subject_pk PRIMARY KEY(subject_id,subject_name)
);
```

**I tried that too but I keep getting the same error**

```
ALTER TABLE category ADD CONSTRAINT some_constraint PRIMARY KEY(category_id,category_name);
```

third table;

```
CREATE TABLE process(
    process_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    fk_category_id INTEGER,
    fk_subject_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_category_id) REFERENCES category(category_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE 
    CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_subject_id) REFERENCES subject(subject_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE 
    CASCADE
    
);
```

Comment: In your `FOREIGN KEY` declaration either: 1) Include both the columns that make up the `PRIMARY KEY` on `category` and `subject`  e.g. `... REFERENCES category(category_id, category_name) ...` or 2) Do not refer to any column and let the FK pick up the PK automatically e.g. `... REFERENCES category ON DELETE ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `identity` column isn't automatically a primary key. So your tables `category` and `subject`don't have any primary keys and thus can't be referenced by a foreign key.

You need to add `PRIMARY KEY` to the columns of the tables `category` and `subject`

Comment: yes, that's what I'm asking. As I showed above, I can only add a primary key to my id column. but I cannot create two primary keys in a table or when I create it, the foreign key in my process table does not accept

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is just that , so you can't have two of them on a given table.

Comment: and above I define primary key constraint for my category and subject table. it doesn't happen though

Comment: The OP does have a compound `PRIMARY KEY` defined on each table. See table definitions.

Comment: so defining a primary key constraint doesn't make that column a primary key?

Comment: so I can only complete one primary key

Comment: so how do i define a varchar i want to be unique?

Comment: Create a `UNIQUE` index per [Create Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html).

Comment: You didn't define a PK on a column but on a pair of columns, that means the PK uniqueness is based on the combination and you can't treat each column separately as a PK.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: oh, I didn't see that. Unfortunately I can't delete my answer because it was accepted :(

Answer (score 3):

In your `FOREIGN KEY` declaration either:

1. Include both the columns that make up the `PRIMARY KEY` on `category` and `subject`  e.g. `... REFERENCES category(category_id, category_name) ...`

OR

2. Do not refer to any column and let the FK pick up the PK automatically e.g. `... REFERENCES category ON DELETE ...`.

I am going to say that what you are really after is:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
    category_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(210) UNIQUE,
    category_description TEXT
    
);

CREATE TABLE subject(
    subject_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    subject_name VARCHAR(210) UNIQUE,
    subject_description TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE process(
    process_id  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    fk_category_id INTEGER,
    fk_subject_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_category_id) REFERENCES category ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE 
    CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_subject_id) REFERENCES subject ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE 
    CASCADE
    
);
```